# closure algorithm

Tags: sql

Ищу статью про closure algorithm of functional dependency. Мне нужно даказательство того что результат алгоритма является покрытием заданных аттрибутов.

Comment: эта статья вам может быть будет полезна [http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter6/node12.html](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter6/node12.html)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.